# CodeIgniter 3 using Steam/OpenID Api

Tags: codeigniter, openid, steam

I'm using codeigniter 3 with this steam-api: https://github.com/alemohamad/ci-steam-api

After sign in through steam I have in $_SESSION['steam_id'] my steamid but when I try to use

```
$this->steamapi->getUserID();
```

it's return *User is not logged in.*

I have in autoload session and I have configured the steam API KEY.

Someone know what can be wrong with this?

Comment: looks like it is an issue: check: https://github.com/alemohamad/ci-steam-api/issues/1

Comment: @Vickel this man told only where is propably problem but he didn't fix it.

Comment: @Vickel it isn't his library, he is only user of it.

Comment: they say the steam user id of the logged in user is in a session variable. There is no such getUserID() method ? please check.